# using Multiple LDAPproviderURLs in AuthenticationConfig.xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I am using LDAP Login Module in Worklight to authenticate users. I have provided the IP Address of one of my Domain Controllers in ldapProviderUrl, and everything is working perfectly fine.

> Now, I want to add the second Domain Controller as a backup for
>   authentication in case the Primary DC is down.

Any one has any idea if I can add another ldapProviderUrl in authenticationConfig.xml ? I have already tried using the Generic Domain Address, but that is not working at all.

I am using Worklight 6.0.1 , and class com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule .

Answer (score 1):

The ldapProviderUrl parameter is used to specify the java.naming.provider.url
environment property for the LdapContext. And I believe that property can be
a comma separated list of URLs for failover. Try specifying a comma separated
list of URLs for the ldapProviderUrl parameter.