# Inputting multiple ldapProviderUrls in worklight

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

This is a duplicate question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21401786/1796386) but it has yet to be answered and i could not comment on it because i do not have the reputation to. The only answer there was to try separating the URLs with a comma but it still does not work for me.

I am trying to have a single adapter that can handle the logins of 2 different types of users. The IP Addresses to these 2 type of users are both using different IP addresses.

Here's what i have tried,

```
<parameter name="ldapProviderUrl" value="ldap://111.11.11.11:389/, ldap://222.22.22.22:389/" />
```

Please note that the IP addresses are made up.

I have even done something like this for ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern and ldapSearchBase but it does not work too.

```
<parameter name="ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" value="{username}@user1.somewhere, {username}@user2.somewhere/>
<parameter name="ldapSearchBase" value="dc=xxx,dc=abc,dc=def, dc=yyy,dc=abc,dc=def"/>
```

I am not sure if it is possible hence any help would be greatly appreciated. 

Thank you.

Comment: I am the one who asked the question in past, and I can confirm the comma separated value approach didn't work for me either.

Comment: Yup. What i am trying now is to create 1 adapter for each LDAP url but that hasn't been working properly. Not even sure if it's the right way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using Multiple LDAPproviderURLs in AuthenticationConfig.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401786/using-multiple-ldapproviderurls-in-authenticationconfig-xml)

Answer (score 0):

I need to confirm this, but as far as i know The LDAP adapter doesn't have the ability to query multiple servers.

A possible workaround is to merge both LDAP servers into one proxy LDAP server that would query both urls behind the scenes.

Check here on how this can be done:

https://serverfault.com/questions/106869/how-can-i-proxy-multiple-ldap-servers-and-still-have-grouping-of-users-on-the-p

http://ltb-project.org/wiki/documentation/general/sasl_delegation